# How to import an angular project modules in another angular project without packaging the project?

Tags: angular

I want to reuse existing project within another angular project?

Is that possible without packaging the project?

As in: I have 2 angular projects/apps running separately. Now I have to import some of the feature modules from those 2 angular projects into a new angular project. How could I do that?

Comment: Specify more information so your question become a bit narrower and easier to interpret

Comment: I have 2 angular projects/apps running separately. Now I have to import some of the feature modules from those 2 angular projects into a new angular project. How do we do that?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Note: never put more info into comments, update your question instead.